# Getting auto increment ID in contact form 7

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm struggling to have an auto increment ID working in a dynamic field when a user submits a form. How should the custom table get updated for every submission entry? & How should we get the id from the custom table?

Create Table with auto increment:

```
function create_db() {
    global $wpdb;

    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "id_count";
    if($wpdb->get_var("show tables like '$table_name'") != $table_name) {
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
                `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                `name` mediumtext NOT NULL,
                UNIQUE KEY id (id)
        )$charset_collate;";

        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
        dbDelta($sql);
    }

}   
add_action("init", "create_db");
```

When form submit:

```
function your_wpcf7_posted_data( $posted_data ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $name = $posted_data['your-name'];

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "id_count";
    $posted_data['cf7-counter'] = $wpdb->insert_id;  
);
```

Comment: As a general rule: Don't use the ID in your form, it will be created automatically when you insert the data in the database.

Comment: is there any resource that i can look at? currently my form sents to the cfdb plugin which doesn't consist of an auto increment column http://cfdbplugin.com/

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. Yet you probably still get a valid auto increment value? The question is: Why do you want the auto increment value in your form? For updates?

Comment: i wanted to have an unique sequential number so that we can keep track of all the form submission. eg. WM001, WM002. Random number doesn't solve the process as they can't determine the correct order to follow up.

Comment: Every time your code submits a form, and inserts the data in the database, the auto increment column, in the database table, will get a value that is one higher than the previous insert. There's no need, other than making the column auto incremental in the database, to supply a number with the form submission.

Comment: i see! thx for pointing this out for the dynamic field. But how do I associate this custom table to add an entry with each form submission action?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your sql code is not working properly so you can try below code :

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  $table_name (
            `id` int(9) NOT NULL,
             `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
```

) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=262 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ";

Answer (score 0):

Hi If you are looking dynamic number generation into contact form 7 this WordPress guide will help you.

**Steps:**

Theme function.php add this code

```
function wpcf7_generate_rand_number( $wpcf7_data ) {
$properties = $wpcf7_data->get_properties();
$shortcode = '[rand-generator]';
$mail = $properties['mail']['body'];
$mail_2 = $properties['mail_2']['body'];
if( preg_match( "/{$shortcode}/", $mail ) || preg_match( "/[{$shortcode}]/", $mail_2 ) ) {
$option = 'wpcf7sg_' . $wpcf7_data->id();
$sequence_number = (int)get_option( $option ) + 1;
update_option( $option, $sequence_number );</code>
$properties['mail']['body'] = str_replace( $shortcode, $sequence_number, $mail );
$properties['mail_2']['body'] = str_replace( $shortcode, $sequence_number, $mail_2 );
$wpcf7_data->set_properties( $properties );
}
}
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_generate_rand_number' );
```

Then use field `[rand-generator]`

Source:
https://www.banna360.com/contact-from7-dynamic-number-generation/